# What is Rubygem's equivalent of the '-I' flag?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I build a project with gcc, I can use the very useful `-I` flag to specify additional include dirs. Sometimes, gems require code to be compiled, but I can't use the `-I` flag. Specifically, I can't build RMagick on my machine because it fails on the MagickWand step:

```
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... no
```

I know exactly where `MagickWand.h` is. How do I tell gem where to find it?

**UPDATE:**
I have two versions of ImageMagick on my system (for work) and gem throws this error:

```
Warning: Found more than one ImageMagick installation. This could cause problems at runtime.
     /a/Magick-config reports version 6.5.8 Q8 is installed in [a]
     /b/Magick-config reports version 6.6.4 Q16 is installed in [b]
Using 6.5.8 Q8 from [a].
```

gem is using version `[a]` whereas I want it to use version `[b]`...but I can't find any way to have it switch to `[b]`. As far as I can tell, gem doesn't consult my `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

The [guides](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem_install) indicate that like you can pass build options

> If an extension fails to compile during gem installation the gem specification is not written out, but the gem remains unpacked in the repository. You may need to specify the path to the library’s headers and libraries to continue. You can do this by adding a – between RubyGems’ options and the extension’s build options:

```
$ gem install some_extension_gem
[build fails]
Gem files will remain installed in /path/to/gems/some_extension_gem-1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /path/to/gems/some_extension_gem-1.0/gem_make.out
$ gem install some_extension_gem -- --with-extension-lib=/path/to/lib
[build succeeds]
$ gem list some_extension_gem

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

some_extension_gem (1.0)
$
```

For you, that sounds like `gem install rmagick -- -I /path/to/MagickWand.h` but I'm not really sure how to try it out to verify.